# Integromat Watch Google Contacts - What to do for DELETE actions?

Tags: make.com

With the "Watch Contacts" Google Contact module, you can track when I contact is added or edited. What about when a contact is deleted? Contact deletion seems to give no trigger at all.

I am using this module to "mirror" my contacts to my companies Domain Shared Contacts so that everyone on my domain has access to the same contacts as I do. Works great, even with email autofills. Just worrying about dead contacts piling up in the shared directory over time.

Only thing I can think of is to create another Integromat routine to periodically compare the Directory contacts to mine and delete any non-matches.

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

APIs rarely support the action of deleting objects, so the solution you're suggesting seems to be the only option for now.